# eBay Purchase history doesn't match information on other parts of web site

Tags: ebay

I am looking at an [eBay seller's Feedback](http://feedback.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewFeedback2&userid=brickfence&ftab=AllFeedback&myworld=true&rt=nc&_trksid=p2050430.m2531.l4585). One of the most recent is from buyer `i***4`:

[image: feedback]

When I click on the "View Item" link to go to the [item he bought](http://www.ebay.com/itm/MACBOOK-PRO-A1226-A1260-A1261-A1229-LOGIC-BOARD-REPAIR-NEW-CHIPSET-GPU-INSTALL-/110977450315) it tells me that 18 were sold:

[image: 18 sold]

When I click on the "18 sold" link to go to the [item's Purchase history](http://offer.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewBidsLogin&item=110977450315&rt=nc&_trksid=p2047675.l2564), it shows that only 12 were sold (7 Buy It Now and 5 Accepted offers) and none of the 12 buyers has the user ID `i***4`:

[image: Purchase history]

Why does the item's Purchase history show fewer than 18 purchases and none of the User IDs is `i***4`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm an eBay seller and have often wondered that myself. However the answer is actually quite simple. eBay only stores 3 months of history (90 days I think) and any sales prior to that just don't display.

The buyer `i***4` must have purchased earlier than the 90 days and has only left feedback recently. Sometimes people take a long time to leave feedback, if at all.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right.  I just checked the Purchase History for that item again, and all the May transactions are gone - it only shows back to the June 25th transaction (which is over 90 days old, but I bet that will disappear by Oct 25th).